# Check if order of numbers in matrix is equal to predefined sequence of numbers

Tags: matlab

I have a `matrix <1x5000>` named `values`. What I do now is to check if certain values are existing in that matrix, like this:

```
if any(values == 10) && any(values == 45) && any(values == 55) and so on
plot graph here
end
```

What this do is to check whether the numbers 10, 45, 55 are existing *somewhere* in that matrix. *Now* I want to change this statement to instead check for numbers coming in a pre-defined order after each other, in other words not only check if they exist. Example:

```
if values has 10, 25, 35, 55, 60 <- they must come like this, not mixed
do stuff
end
```

Help would be greatly appreciated as I am new with Matlab.

Have so far tried:

```
values = [10, 50, 30, 60, 40];

[~, indices] = ismember([10, 50, 30, 60, 40], values);

if all(indices > 0) && issorted(indices)
    % Do stuff
end
```

Without any success, the if statement is never satisfied.

So to make it more clear, if I set values = [10, 20, 50, 25, 33]; there must somewhere in the matrix come values after each other in the exact same way as I set it. Example: matrix: 10, 55, 90, 33, 10, 20, 50, 25, 33, 100, 59 would give true as there is one sequence of 10, 20, 50, 25, 33

Comment: What if there are other numbers in the `10, 25, 35, 55, 60` sequence? An example would be  `10, 100, 25, 200, 35, 300, 55, 400, 60, 500`; would this count as fulfilling your condition of "numbers coming in a pre-defined order after each other"? A concrete example with expected results would be nice.

Comment: What if there are repetitions of those numbers and some combinations breaks the order while other satisfies, `10, 100, 25, 10, 200, 35, 300, 55, 400, 60, 500`:  this sequence satisfies your order if you consider only the first `10`.

Comment: @edwinksl This would not fulfill my condition, no other values are allowed to be in between.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to determine if an *exact* series of values appears within your array, you can use `strfind`. Although the function was created for strings, it also works for numeric datatypes. If there sub-array exists in the array, then the output of `strfind` is the index of the occurances, otherwise if the sub-array does not exist, the output is an empty array `[]`.

```
if ~isempty(strfind(values, [10 25 35 55 60]))
    % Do stuff
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately this isn't working for me. I set it up with values = [10, 20, 50, 25, 33]; but the if statement is never executed. Have also tried with different values without success. I think you have misunderstood my question, I don't want to check if next value is bigger but it it comes in order.

Comment: So to make it more clear, if I set values = [10, 20, 50, 25, 33]; there must somewhere in the matrix come values after each other in the exact same way as I set it. Example: matrix: 10, 55, 90, 33, 10, 20, 50, 25, 33, 100, 59 would give true as there is one sequence of 10, 20, 50, 25, 33.

Comment: @HumbleMan Ok it wasn't clear that you needed an exact copy like that. I have updated my answer.

Comment: While matrix: 10, 55, 80, 44, 90, 20, 50, 25, 80, 60, 33 would give false as there is no sequence of 10, 20, 50, 25, 33 that exists in that order.

Comment: @HumbleMan Using my updated answer, that does give a false output.